# npm run build & npm start not working, react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, npm-start

I am a new react student, have no place else to ask this question and can't solve it on my own because I'm really confused, I don't even know how to put this question together properly. I'm following the instructions from a react course.

I installed node.js, created a new project folder, then in the terminal I wrote `create react-app .` everything worked, and then wrote `npm run build` and `npm start`, but both didn't work.

Heres the error messages for `npm run build`:

```
> github-finder@0.1.0 build C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder
> react-scripts build

"Courses\github-finder\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! github-finder@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the github-finder@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-18T02_07_40_371Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder> npm run build

> github-finder@0.1.0 build C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder
> react-scripts build

"Courses\github-finder\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! github-finder@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the github-finder@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-18T02_10_32_763Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder>
```

And heres the code for `npm start`

```
> github-finder@0.1.0 start C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder
> react-scripts start

"Courses\github-finder\node_modules\.bin\" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! github-finder@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the github-finder@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-18T02_11_45_759Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\liana\Documents\My stuff\Webdev\Practice Projects & Courses\github-finder>
```

some messages are in russian, if you need translation use the translator or ask me to leave the translation here, whatever you prefer

Thank you for reading this, I'm desperate and need help, nothing on the internet helped me just yet

Comment: Have you run `npm i`?

Comment: @dwjohnston nope, I'll try, thanks

Comment: @dwjohnston didn't help, i even created a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works.
Using the command node `node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js` does the same thing as `npm start`, though I don't know what's the catch here. Works for me. Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8221

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to create your project based on "create-react...."
You have to use the exactly command "npx create-react-app 'yournameProject'"
Then open your folder in a text editor like visual code and run the following command -> "npm start"
It shouldnt give you error

About your problem: I think you have stepped something

So try to use first "npm i" then "npm start"

Comment: Tried doing all this in a new project, did not work, but thank you anyways! I found a different solution, have a look in the answers if you want

Comment: Well, no problem, but.. that's weird